# Custom permalink with %tags% breaking archive pagination, but not for category archive pagination

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, pagination, archive, permalinks

I've changed my permalink structure to use `/resources/%tags%/%postname%/`

To get `%tags%` to work I included a function found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97394/how-to-use-all-tags-in-post-permalinks)

I have custom pagination using `get_pagenum_link()`, which works fine, so long as I am at something like `/resources/category/recent/page/2/`. Even `/resources/tag/podcasts/page/2/` works

However, `/resources/page/2/` leads to a 404.

I think I need to customize a rewrite_rule, but all attempts have failed and I do not quite understand how to rewrite for archive pagination to work.

I've tried the following:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule('(.?.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top');
});
```

This fixes it on the main archive page, but now breaks on category archive.

Answer (score 0):

Here was the fix in the end:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule('(resources)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top');
});
```

This way the rewrite only targets **resources** with a paginated url.